# Choosing the right subscription membership add-on

Tags: members, subscriptions

I'm updating a very old EE1.7 site for a local charity and their current site runs membership subscriptions through [AMember](http://www.amember.com/). It's worked pretty well but it's not an ee module and the integration is pretty clunky (at least it is with this EE1.7 site). I've been looking at the current options and as far as I can see it comes down to three candidates - [Charge](http://squarebit.co.uk/software/expressionengine/charge), [Cartthrob Subscriptions](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/subscriptions) and [DevDemon's subscriptions](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/subscriptions).

Because they're a charity that deal with all sorts of organisations they still need to be able to handle offline payments for subscriptions (cheques) and be able to generate invoices for them. But it would still be nice to handle all of the other automated functionality (expiry notices, renewal notification emails etc) from EE. Also because memberships are open to individuals, students and organisations there needs to be multiple levels of membership.

Cartthrob's solution is out because the client budget can't stretch to it. DevDemon can't do this out of the box and I'm fairly certain that charge can't do it either (they haven't come back to me, but I think their product is for a strictly 'modern' customer base).

So my questions are - is there anything out there that *can* do this (an addon, or a way of thinking!), and has anyone used AMember in the last few years? Is the integration any better than it was for EE1? Because I'm pretty sure that product can handle the offline / online payments issue, but it's my least favourite way forward because all administration seems to be separate from the EE control panel.

Comment: This is an 'opinion' question rather than a technical problem - where should I be asking it if not here?

Comment: I'd suggest contacting the add-on devs directly to see if their solutions can meet your needs. CartThrob is no longer under development though, so I'd advise against it as an option.